# Show/Hide Database Field based on Null/Not Null ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to hide a data field if it is null via ASP.NET.
I have the following setup:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/vb">
// target the id called test
var test = document.getElementById("test");

// if test is not empty, show
// else hide test
if (test.value != null){
    document.getElementById("test").style.visibility = visible;
}else{
    document.getElementById("test").style.visibility = hidden;
}
```

```
<p><asp:Label runat="server" id="test"><%# Eval("DBField")%></asp:Label></p>
```

Am I way off here? I am getting error in whatever I try. I don't think it should be so complicated however...any thoughts/recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advanced,

Comment: What error are you getting?  Is there a reason you are using Javascript to do this instead of the code behind?

Comment: I am new to ASP.NET, I'm not sure how to do the code behind. How best can I learn that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to hide data via the following code:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder" runat="server" Visible='<%# IIf((Eval("test")).ToString().Length > 0, "true", "false") %>'>
     <h3>test</h3>
     <asp:Label ID="test" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("test") %>'></asp:Label>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your error is it's hard to give you an answer.  One thing that jumps out is that you are not using the ClientId of the asp.net control.  Try changing this:

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
```

to this:

```
var test = document.getElementById("<%=test.ClientID%>");
```

When you assign an ID to an asp.net control, that is not the ID that gets rendered.  Give [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) a read for more info on that.

Comment: Put what on the page load event on the server side?

Comment: I receive this error "BC30188: Declaration expected." for this same line you are referencing here.

Comment: Your page should contain a .cs file. You can put code there that is executed before the page is rendered to the client. There you will have access to the label and can do test.Visible=false/true.

Comment: Thanks for your help in reference topics for me to look into. I really need a good book or class on this to better grasp concepts but am learning best I can on my own at the moment. I appreciate everyone's feedback, this is great! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible issues here:

Since you are using a server control, depending on what its parent is, the ASP.NET runtime could be changing its ID.  If you View Source on your page it may show an ID like "ctl00_main_test" or something similar.  To get aroud this you have to do the followinh:

```
var test = document.getElementById("<%= test.ClientID %>");

if (test.text != null){
    test.style.visibility = 'visible';
}else{
    test.style..visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Since "visibility" maps to a CSS style, you probably have to use quotes around "visible" and "hidden"

Lastly, **getElementByID** should work well for all modern browsers, but older browsers could have flaky implementations.  I suggest looking at **[jquery](http://jquery.com/)** to simplify this code:

```
if ( $('#<%=test.ClientID>').text() != '' && $('#<%=test.ClientID%>').text() != null){
    $('#<%=test.ClientID%>').show();
}else{
    $('#<%=test.ClientID%>').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. For some reason in all examples listed in everyone's suggestions, I'm still stuck at the first line defining the var...The error is the same?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test against empty string in JavaScript, like this:

```
var test = document.getElementById("<%=test.ClientID%>");
if (test){
    test.style.visibility = (test.value == "" ? "hidden" : "visible");
}
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed that you're using databinding syntax, which makes me think that this Label is inside of a grid or something. You can try something like this instead:

```
<asp:Label ID="test" runat="server" Visible='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DBField")) == false)%>'><%#Eval("DBField")</asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still getting error on my var. All suggestions here are recommending this line. I don't understand the error, and I don't get much details on this line

Comment: Did you see my second suggestion? The problem is that the Label is inside of a databound control, so you won't be able to access it using `document.getElementById`. See my suggested edit.

Comment: Thanks James. Hmmm, I'm not sure I understand what your edits are. What can be used instead of document.getElementById? I still need the top script with the var right?...not just the second part...?

Answer (score 0):

`Span` tags do not have a value:

```
if ($('#<%=test.ClientID%>').html() != "") //jQuery
```

or

```
if (document.getElementById("<%=test.ClientID%>").innerText != "")
```

Comment: Why the reference to span tags? Should I be using these somewhere?